# How to use sub query value in the main query in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use the inner query value to add a column in the main query.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(ID,Name,SysAge1,sysAge2,SysAgeType)
SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    (SELECT age1 FROM Person WHERE idx = 1) as sysAge1,
    (SELECT age2 FROM Person WHERE idx = 2) as sysAge2,
    Case
        WHEN (sysAge1 >0) OR (sysAge2 >0)  Then 'A'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS SysAgeType
```

I am getting the below error in the Case statement,

```
Invalid column name 'sysAge1'
Invalid column name 'sysAge2'
```

I am not sure how to use nested query inside a select section. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: From your snippet it seems that you are creating a table view and SysAge is your column name. You cannot use 'sysAge1' as that column is not yet created.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to `JOIn`?

Comment: Yes- JOIN will do the job. I didn't think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would could try something like this

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1(ID,Name,SysAge1,sysAge2,SysAgeType)
SELECT 
   *, 
   CASE
        WHEN (sysAge1 >0) OR (sysAge2 >0)  Then 'A'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS SysAgeType 
FROM
   (SELECT
      ID,
      NAME,
      (SELECT age1 FROM Person WHERE idx = 1) as sysAge1,
      (SELECT age2 FROM Person WHERE idx = 2) as sysAge2,
    FROM TBL) TBL2
```

Comment: In the second SELECT, we need use alias for each column, like ID as ID, Name as Name etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use normal joins

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1
  (ID, Name, SysAge1, sysAge2, SysAgeType)
SELECT
    ID,
    NAME,
    p1.Age,
    p2.Age,
    Case
        WHEN (p1.Age > 0) OR (p2.Age > 0)  Then 'A'
        ELSE 'B'
    END AS SysAgeType
FROM SomeTableHere
LEFT JOIN Person p1 ON p1.idx = 1
LEFT JOIN Person p2 ON p2.idx = 2;
```

You can also use `APPLY` if you need a proper subquery.